# Schema Association in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 models:

Here is the User Model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  facebook: String,
  twitter: String,
  tokens: Array,

  profile: {
    name: String,
    gender: String,
    location: String,
    website: String,
    picture: String
  }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

And here is the Revive Model:

```
const reviveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  reviveShowName: {type: String, required: true},
  reviveTitle: {type: String, required: true},
  reviveCategory: {type: String, required: true},
  reviveGoal: {type: Number, required: true},
  revivePhoto: {type: String, required: true},
  reviveVideo: {type: String},
  reviveStory: {type: String},
  author: {
      id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
      },
      name: String
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

In the Revive model, I'm trying to the reference the author and get the author's id and that works... How do I also get the name from profiles -> name...? Clearly `name: String` is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose relations work, based on the `ref` and `type` value of the nested object. In your case you have associated the `id` property of `author` to point to the `User` model.

If you want to populate the `author` with the user information, you should just do :

```
author: {     
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "User"
}
```

Then in your query you just use populate

```
Revive.find({})
      .populate( 'author' )
      .exec( function( error, docs ) {
          console.log( docs ); // will have `[{author:{profile:{...}}}]` data
      } );
```